# Java Coding Help! Can't get if statement to confirm string

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

Write a program that prompts the user to provide a single character from the alphabet. Print Vowel or Consonant, depending on the user input. If the user input is not a letter (between a and z or A and Z), or is a string of length > 1, print an error message.

I have been trying to solve this problem, and basically have it all figured out but have ran into two issues. How do I get the scanner to recognize an error if the user inputs a number rather than a letter. Also how would one not have to repeat their input. Is there a way to have the first if statement evaluate if the user entered a string?

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MessAround {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please Provide single character from the alphabet: ");
        String letter = scan.next();
        
        if (scan.hasNext())
        {
            letter = letter.toLowerCase();
            if (letter.equals("a") || letter.equals("e") || letter.equals("i") || letter.equals("o") || letter.equals("u"))
            {
                System.out.println("Vowel");
            }
            else if (letter.length() > 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Consonant");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `isDigit()` to see weather the user entered a number instead of a character, I didn't undersand the second question

Comment: Why do you check "if(scan.hasNext())" You already have a string from the scanner from the first "String letter = scan.next();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this. A couple of them are as follows:

**Using Regex:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please Provide single character from the alphabet: ");
        String letter = scan.next();

        if (!letter.matches("[A-Za-z]")) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        } else {
            letter = letter.toLowerCase();
            if (letter.matches("[aeiou]")) {
                System.out.println("Vowel");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Consonant");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Learn about regex from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

**Using the class, [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html):**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please Provide single character from the alphabet: ");
        String letter = scan.next();

        if (letter.length() == 1 && Character.isAlphabetic(letter.charAt(0))) {
            char ch = Character.toLowerCase(letter.charAt(0));
            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
                System.out.println("Vowel");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Consonant");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `if`s: `if (isNumber(letter)) { // A number was entered.` and create a `isNumber(String)` method that returns `true` if the string is a number in the sense that you mean it.

Or better make it a `String isValid(String)` method and implement in the method your validation rules. It could return `null` if the validation is successful otherwise a message.